# A Great-Aunt's Cryptic Invitation

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, story, english, letters

My great-aunt is one of those stuffy old ladies whose house looks like it was transported intact from the 1950s.  It always smells a little like mothballs, and the amount of framed embroideries and cross-stitch on the walls makes it difficult to determine the pattern on the faded wallpaper.

She's a nice enough person, but not exactly the most scintillating conversationalist, if you know what I mean.

Anyway, she's been trying for years to get me to come to her house for a visit, but I've always "unfortunately" had something else scheduled whenever she tries to make a date.  I'm sure she's figured out by now that I'm brushing her off, but she doggedly keeps trying.

She recently learned that I'm a big puzzle fan, and shortly thereafter, the following email appeared in my inbox:

> **From:** Great Aunt Edna
>   **To:** GentlePurpleRain
>   **Subject:** Won't you join me for tea?
>
> My dear great-nephew.  You have avoided me long enough.  Please solve the following, and then we can discuss it when you come to visit.
>
> Much love, Aunt Edna
>
> ```
> FU DD IR RH
> EH NF UR LE
> 2M TH UL MN
> NX SS DN NR
> S2 ½½ MT
> ```

She just cornered me at the latest family gathering with a calendar and made me pick a date and time to get together.  Can you help me solve the puzzle so that we at least have something in common to discuss when we meet?

---

**Notes/Hints**

- *Yes, I am aware of [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717)*
- *Yes, I tagged this puzzle correctly.  No additional tags are needed.*
- *The story is 99% flavourtext.  There are a few small hints as to the content of the message, but nothing that will help you solve the puzzle.*

---

**EDIT:**
I fear that I may have misled people by declaring that "no additional tags are needed."  When I wrote that, I was thinking mostly of the [cipher](/questions/tagged/cipher) tag, which does not apply here.  There is one tag that I considered adding, but, getting a little pedantic, I felt that it didn't *directly* apply.  It probably would, however, give a lot of clues as to the solution of the puzzle.  Since there has been little progress as yet, I will mention it here:  [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus)  This puzzle doesn't fit the tag, according to the tag description, but it certainly does employ certain similar methods.

---

**Hint**

> The spaces are entirely irrelevant to the puzzle.  They only serve to structure it a little more nicely. Try munging all the letters together and see if that helps at all.

Comment: Intrigued. For those who missed it, there's a [tag:rhyme] tag here with no obvious rhymes (yet!).  Also [tag:english] and [tag:letters] tags.

Comment: Hm, those `½`s are very suspicious...

Comment: What's suspicious with the rhyme tag is that it came *after* the hint "Yes, I tagged this puzzle correctly. No additional tags are needed." was already present in the puzzle.

Comment: @hvd Don't dwell on that too much.  It's there because the solution rhymes.  I hadn't thought to put it in at first, and it certainly isn't *needed*.

Comment: is the name "Edna" important or am I thinking nonsense?

Comment: @lois6b Not important. Like I said, the story is non-essential to the puzzle.

Comment: ouch, I was comparing with dna-related terms xD

Comment: I can make a reasonable sentence fragment by making two words out of the first block and one word out of the second+third blocks. Similar approaches give valid sensible fragments with later letters. I'm not able to turn the fragments into complete sentences and I have no idea if I'm on completely the wrong track, but if not, this may help someone else.

Comment: @hvd  It sounds like you're on the right track.   I will say no more just yet.

Comment: @hvd What do you mean by "blocks"? Each row, or each pair of letters?

Comment: @DanRussell Pairs. It was the same idea that TwoBitOperation now put into an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Continuing form @TwoBitOperation's work:

Put all

> characters into a long string, then read the letters phonetically, pluralizing where appropriate (DD=deez, RR=arz).
>
>  **FUDDIRRHEHNFURLE2MTHULMNNXSSDNNRS2½½MT**

Aunt Edna is telling you, in rhyme,

> FUDDIRRHEHN
>  If you desire satiation,
>
>  FURLE2MT
>  If you are really too empty,
>
>  HULMNNXSS
>  Eschew all immense excesses;
>
>  DNNRS2½½MT
>  The answer is to have some tea.

Comment: Very close.  I'll give you the third line, because it was the weakest, and I don't expect you to get it from context.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Ah! I had immense (and excesses) at various points, but never connected to eschew.  Cleverly done.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain And good luck with Aunt Edna! Looks like you guys could play some Mad Gab and have a good time after all. ;)

Comment: Nice work!  I hope you sounded as weird as I did repeatedly saying these letters out loud.

Comment: @TwoBitOperation Totally. My wife walked in at one point when I was mumbling and trying to vary the emphasis on the third line: "hUlmnnXSs", "HulMnnXSS", "hULmNNxSx"...  Then she walked out.

Answer (score 5):

OK, the trick seems to be:

> Read each letter phonetically (F = "eff").  When there are two of the same  letters in a row, read it as a plural (DD = "Dees").  Pronouncing it this way leads to the message.

Partial, nonsensical answer for others to work off of, or to be edited as I get more:

> If you desire sage 
> Each and if you are **LE**
> To empty a jewel, a man's
> Excesses, the answer
> is two halves empty

Comment: Right idea, but the solution is far from correct.  The correct solution is not nonsensical.

Comment: I know what I have is incomplete, but I wanted to jumpstart others on finding the answer.  Can you tell me if my method is correct, and my issue is just in the parsing, or if there are other rules I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, your method is correct.  The issue is just the parsing.

Comment: I started down this path also, but after the first doublet I was like "FU2" and quit.